# How to add data points to a trained KNN

Tags: machine-learning, python, k-nn

I have a trained KNN, I created with
https://github.com/kevinzakka/blog-code/blob/master/knn/knn.py

I want to add more data points to the KNN but I am on a raspberry pi so limited by RAM and therefore the number of data points I can add at a time to the model.

I have 20k images, I can add 2k at a time. Because of the way scikitlearn works, I cant use the model trained on a Windows PC on the pi (different architectures).

Can I create a model, and then add more data points to it somehow?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28006451/7006323

Comment: Maybe try using pickle to store trained models for each iteration and discard the rest of the unwanted data.

Answer (score 1):

Re-estimating parameters with additional data is called [online machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning).

Scikit-learn is **not** designed for online learning. [Scikit-multiflow](https://scikit-multiflow.github.io/) is designed for online learning.